# Mobile browser doesn't show views even when badges granted by views are shown in notification bar

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, mobile-web, views

It's Thanksgiving, so I'm getting my Gaming SE fix through my mobile iPhone browser. I recently received a notable question badge for 'How do I defeat a wispmother in Skyrim?' and wanted to see just how many views it got. I didn't expect to see it initially, but once I sorted by views, I at least expected to see the number of views the question had.

Expected behavior: either views should be populated for questions when sorting by views in the mobile browser or there should be some intuitive way to see views on the mobile browser.

Answer (score 3):

The mobile browser is not supposed to have all the features.

It's supposed to be able to do all the necessary and somewhat-necessary stuff, that's it.

I hardly look at views, and I believe it's the same for others. The feature's peripheral, not really necessary. The mobile site has to save up on bandwidth, RAM, screen real-estate, etc, so all these unnecessary things aren't there.